# Does this coding answer look good?

Tags: assembly, machine-code, high-level

In school I was told to describe the difference between machine-, assembly-, and high-level computer languages.

> Give an example of machine language code and assembly language code and then name two high-level languages

And this is my answer:

"Machine and assembly are made up of instructions that the computer directly executes. High level is programming languages that are closer to English than machine language. For machine code my example would be things like binary, like 1101 or 1001. C is an assembly language code. Java and python are high level languages."

Comment: C is a high level language. In assembly language, the source corresponds directly to machine instructions.

Comment: C generally compiles, ultimately to machine code for the instruction set.  java and python typically compile to the bytecode for the virtual machine, not for the target processor...but all three are most definitely high level languages, no question.

Comment: Use `objdump -d /bin/ls` (on GNU/Linux for example) to disassemble a program and see machine code (or a hexdump of it) and the corresponding assembly source representation of the same instructions.  1101 isn't anything, although probably some toy machine with 4-bit instructions could be imagined or even exists on paper.

Answer (score 7):

Machine code is arguably unreadable; where instructions are encoded as numbers: as fields of numbers; numbers for offsets, numbers for constants, numbers for opcodes, numbers for registers.  There are no code labels, no data labels — just numbers.

Assembly language introduces mnemonics, register names, and (yay!) labels — and this source code is readable as text.  Though more readable, and importantly more easily edited, none-the-less, lines of assembly mostly correspond directly to machine code instructions.

"High-level" computer languages are also human readable text, though have at least 2 features that differentiate from assembly language.  First, the notion of structured statements.  And, second, variations on types & declarations.

Structured statements (if-then, if-then-else, while, for, do-while, functions) allow logical nesting of control structures without using labels — a huge improvement over assembly language.

Types help prevent illegal program states, often at compile time — a program that tries to multiply a string gets a compile-time error — not being allowed to run at all.

In a high level language program we can declare a variable with a type, and that type for that variable is honored for the duration of the program.  A machine code (or assembly) program also knows about types, but much less by declarations, instead rather by repetition in the instruction stream — each time a variable is accessed a type-appropriate instruction variation should be used (sign, data size, etc..).